# Recommendation algorithm based on cutomer tastes

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on a tourism app. The challenge that I have right now is how to recommend to the client certain activities/services based on their tastes. These tastes are tags that the client adds to their profile, on the other end, the activities/services have the same tags. The idea is to show to the client certain activities/services that match the most. I was wondering if there are known techniques to create this particular recommendation algorithm.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The method of recommendation algorithm that you describe called Content-based Filtering, which is documented by [Google](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation/content-based/basics)

Here is is some [implementation](https://heartbeat.comet.ml/recommender-systems-with-python-part-i-content-based-filtering-5df4940bd831) of Content-based filtering using Python.

You can also use the Multi-criteria recommender systems, but i'm having a hard time to find the coding implementation.

I also accidentally found a [book](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/32978074/Recommender_systems_handbook-with-cover-page-v2.pdf?Expires=1636426272&Signature=LG92F83cJ2XcpwNJVuolxj8NhzsI4esWRLpLhIH0N8V6H2eAf7bGWMtMop2qoKhamf1yo6fZy4Xl9ytLR7GIupsqlZgwKv5XX0JZWGh2VfqilON-ep5R0h8bW43V4wen-Pj99eYE2v-OIUj7YEv8KQrbBa2egOoLcam6ZjuWKctcg3p6OsjafXxpbrf8cHmmcD1%7EMKIbDesjX3VVZ5cLMXNbGC6A2djdkbiMCsZAe8I2jw8IKhSuy4kd0uTyHK01U4fxZQf9UqtLJMmLxdSQ4RZKNlGHIedmwqr8zr5wE4dbLCVvWzpPCxEw%7EHQfcSdjLqAH-I9AcpU2PlhRAb7CCA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA#page=774) filled with many other recommendation algorithm including Content-based filter and Multi-criteria recommender systems.